# Arctis Wireless Pro Audio Stopped Working - Kunbutu 18.04

Tags: drivers, sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, plasma

I've been using an Arctis Wireless Pro headset for some months on my Kunbutu laptop but it suddenly decided a earlier whilst I was on a Skype call to loose audio and I'm struggling to get it back working again.

The battery is fine and you can hear it turn on and off and the mic is working. If I change the configuration settings in volume control from "Analogue Stereo Output + Analogue Mono Input" to  "Analogue Mono Output + Analogue Stereo Output + Analogue Mono Input" then you can hear things but it's terrible. There were no updates running at the time, as I was in the middle of a Skype call when it happened

Here are my settings:

The Arctic Pro is top for all of the Audio Playback options
[image]

Here's the Plasma audio showing it as the default
[image]

I often have to reset the applications audio to point to the correct input and output as it looses the default and Skype tends to ignore it's own settings.
[image]

Here's the Advanced tab showing the profile

[image]

This image show Skype also being set to use the device

[image]

Here is the output of `aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3266 Analog [ALC3266 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Dock [WD15 Dock], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Dock [WD15 Dock], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Wireless [Arctis Pro Wireless], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Wireless [Arctis Pro Wireless], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

If anyone has any ideas as to what's gone wrong and how to resolve it I would appreciate the help. I tend to find that audio is the biggest trouble I have with Linux and the reason I originally went with the headset was that it worked out the box along side using Bluetooth to connect to my phone.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like your Headset is broken.
But who knows maybe an update to pulseaudio 14 might help.
The new release specifically mentions the arctis pro and that it gets better supported by the new release.

I also need the update for my arctis pro. It still works but the output is kinda quite.

It still is not packaged for my Ubuntu 20.04 but hopefully soon.
If you find out how to update let me know.